# Preserving Object Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, nested

I am creating a program in which users can preserve search terms from session to session. If a search term is preserved by the user, then the data that corresponds to that search term is also preserved. At the beginning of each session, the script discards any old data that should be preserved if it no longer corresponds to an active or connected drive.

However, I am new to working with JSON and such objects in general, so I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this than the way below? Specifically, is there an approach that is more efficient or even prettier than the first `for of` loop and the heavily nested `if,for,for,if` block of code?

```
async function guaranteeData(drives){
  const
    config = await readJson('./config.json'),
    data = await readJson('./data.json')


  // Is there a better way to write this code?

  let
    json = {}

  for (const [drive] of drives) {
    json[drive] = {}
  }

  // if tags have been preserved
  if (config.fileTypes.length > 0) {
    // loop thru all current system drives
    for (const [drive] of drives) {
      // loop thru all preserved tags
      for (const fileType of config.fileTypes) {
        // if current drive has current tag data
        if (data[drive].hasOwnProperty(fileType)) {
          // preserve this data: data[drive][fileType]
          json[drive][fileType] = data[drive][fileType]
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////


  json = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
  await fsp.writeFile('./data.json', json, {
    flag: 'w',
    encoding: 'utf8'
  })
  .then(() => {
    return true
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'EEXIST') {
      return false
    } else {
      throw error
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable to me, though you may be able to leave off the `if (config.fileTypes.length > 0) {` part entirely, since if the length is 0, `for (const fileType of config.fileTypes) {` simply won't perform any iterations

Comment: @CertainPerformance good point !! theres no better alternative to the nested `for/of/if` block of code ?

Comment: The required logic involves a nested loop and a conditional action inside the nested loop, so there's no way around the fundamental nesting you have there

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok thanks for your help. post your answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I would change two things in this

- Remove the `if (config.fileTypes.length > 0)` check as it will be handled the for loop which is afterwards.
- Remove the for loop which assigns the `json[drive]` to empty object inside the for loop where you have nested for loops. This will remove that for loop as well.

It will looks something like

```
async function guaranteeData(drives) {
  const config = await readJson("./config.json");
  const data = await readJson("./data.json");

  const json = {};

  // if tags have been preserved
  // loop thru all current system drives
  for (const [drive] of drives) {
    json[drive] = {};
    // loop thru all preserved tags
    for (const fileType of config.fileTypes) {
      // if current drive has current tag data
      if (data[drive].hasOwnProperty(fileType)) {
        // preserve this data: data[drive][fileType]
        json[drive][fileType] = data[drive][fileType];
      }
    }
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////

  json = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
  await fsp
    .writeFile("./data.json", json, {
      flag: "w",
      encoding: "utf8"
    })
    .then(() => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.code === "EEXIST") {
        return false;
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    });
}
```